Reading a quite old Apache Lucene index failed using latest version 10.0.0

Windows 10
Lucene 10.0.0
JDK 23.0

I'm new to Lucene and Java, trying to open an index which I believe is 8-10 years old. There are four files in the directory:



Name
Size




_0.cfx
47,942 KB


_s.cfs
1,78,687 KB


segments.gen
1 KB


segments_2
1 KB



Java
import java.util.List;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.StoredFields;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexableField;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.search.MatchAllDocsQuery;

public class FieldReader {

    private static final String INDEX_PATH = "indexedfiles";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(INDEX_PATH)));
        //Index searcher
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        //This query will match with all documents in the index
        Query query = new MatchAllDocsQuery();
        //search the index
        TopDocs foundDocs = searcher.search(query, 10);
        // Returns a StoredFields reader for the stored fields of this index. 
        StoredFields storedFields = searcher.storedFields();

        //Let's print out the path of document files and fields
        for (ScoreDoc sd : foundDocs.scoreDocs) {
          Document doc = storedFields.document(sd.doc);
          System.out.println("Path : " + doc.get("path"));
          List<IndexableField> fields = doc.getFields();
            for (IndexableField field : fields) {
                System.out.println("Name : " + field.name() + ", Type : " + field.fieldType().toString());
            }
        }
    }
}

Error
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooOldException:
Format version is not supported
(resource BufferedChecksumIndexInput(MemorySegmentIndexInput(path="D:\IndiaLawLibrary\AHC\s_index\a\segments_2"))): -9 (needs to be between 1071082519 and 1071082519). 
This version of Lucene only supports indexes created with release 9.0 and later.

I have also tried several older versions including the oldest one 3.0.3 but failed to read the index. I just need the data from index, later I will create a new index using the latest version.

If it is only reading, it should be possible, assuming you have the lucene-backwards-codecs in your classpath.
Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(INDEX_PATH));
IndexCommit commit = DirectoryReader.listCommits(directory).getLast();
DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(commit, 0, null);

The 0 is the minimum major version to check against. It is better to know which version of Lucene made the index and use that, but 0 is a catch-all.
If things have changed too much, there isn't a guarantee that you can read the index. Lucene only officially supports N-1 codecs, but this method is specifically for this case. Annoyingly, there isn't an IndexWriter equivalent to lazily reading in the very old and writing in the new.
https://lucene.apache.org/core/10_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/DirectoryReader.html#listCommits(org.apache.lucene.store.Directory)
https://lucene.apache.org/core/10_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/DirectoryReader.html#open(org.apache.lucene.index.IndexCommit,int,java.util.Comparator)
